# Converting Lambert Conformal Conic (LCC) to UTM

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm, pyproj

I have two `numpy` meshgrids (X, Y both 2D) in Lambert Conformal conic with the following information:

[image]

I'd like to directly (or indirectly if not possible) project them to UTM. I have both `pyproj` and `gdal` installed, but wasn't able to figure out how to use them. I found solutions for converting from LCC to WGS84 [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6376/converting-lambert-conformal-conic-to-wgs84-using-proj-4) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/convert-lambert-conformal-conic-to-wgs84), but couldn't use either of them since I don't have all the information needed.

Even if somehow I can convert from `LCC` to `WGS84`, then I can use Python `UTM` package and `utm.from_latlon` to get `UTM` out of it.

I found the following line of code from [here](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/pyproj/):

```
awips221 = Proj(proj='lcc', R=6371200, lat_1=50, lat_2=50,lon_0=-107, ellps='clrk66')
```

And then I can use `transform` from `pyproj`. In that case, is `lat_1` and `lat_2` both `25.0` in my case? What would be `lon_0` and `ellps`?

Using `gdalinfo` we can see `lCC` and `WGS84` projections for the center and four corners of the grid in the picture below:

[image: Projection description using <code>gdalinfo</code>]

Comment: Try `lon_0` -95 and `ellps` wgs84.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I use the transform function (`from pyproj import transform`). Then dine `lccProj` using `lccProj = Proj(proj='lcc', R=6371229, lat_1=25, lat_2=25,lon_0=-95, ellps='wgs84')` and `utmProj` using `utmProj = Proj(proj='utm', zone=10, ellps='WGS84')`. Finally, I transform them with `XX_UTM, YY_UTM = transform(lccProj, utmProj, XX, YY)`. However, I am not getting meaningful results. I am using **zone=10** for no good reason here! Can that be the cause or I am missing something else?

Comment: From [this link](http://all-geo.org/volcan01010/2012/11/change-coordinates-with-pyproj/), using `lccProj` defined the the previous comment, I can also do `lon, lat = lccProj(XX, YY, inverse=True)` and get longitude and latitude. But these value are not correct for some reason.

Comment: What is the extent of your data in degrees West/North? And perhaps can you give the input and output coordinates for a sample point?

Comment: In `lcc` projection, the ranges are `X = [-4226108, 3250179]` and `Y = [-832697, 4368198]` in meters. This should translates to `lat = [22, 60]` and `lon = [-144, -53]` degrees. Two sample points would be  `[X,Y]=[-4226108,-832697]` (bottom left of the grid) and `[X,Y]=[3250179, 4368198]` (upper right of the grid)

Comment: For bottom left, `[X,Y]=[-4226108,-832697]` m which should result in `[lat,lon] = [17.81, -127.077]` degrees

Comment: I'm getting `[10.50, -127.36] for `[X,Y]=[-4226108,-832697]` with current settings.

Comment: Using GDAL cs2cs, I get -133.45901182°E 12.26975675°N for lcc bottom left. I'm not sure whom to trust.

Comment: I don't know. `[17.81, -127.077]` are based on NOAA Weather and climate toolkit program. I am thinking maybe both `lat_1` and `lat_2` shouldn't be 25?

Comment: Maybe. I am using this projection string: `+proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_0=25 +lon_0=-95 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452972/coordinates-conversion-with-pyproj you should be able to use it with pyproj.Proj

Comment: Yes, I am getting `[12.26, -133.45]` using your approach and `[10.50, -127.36]` using mine ([lat, lon]). My guess is that `x_0` and `y_0` might not be zero.

Comment: Can you give a link to the source data?

Comment: The source is a `grib2` file. The description using `gdalinfo` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl6g50e0o5gykd6/gdalinfo.jpg?dl=1) and the file itself can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r1z6sbrm1sk83o2/ten_meter_20150816_00z_01.grib2?dl=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what NOAA thinks are the right coordinates, but I have no problem loading the file into QGIS, or reprojecting it to WGS84 with gdalwarp:

[image]

QGIS uses this custom projection string:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=25 +lat_2=25 +lat_0=25 +lon_0=265 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +units=m +no_defs
```

You can use the same string with pyproj.Proj().

where you can safely replace `lon_0=265` with `lon_0=-95`.

Note that the extent in degrees is not the same as reprojecting the corner coordinates, because the picture is heavily bended.

I'm not sure why you want to transform the data to UTM. It crosses several UTM zones (7N to 21N). You can take the middle one (15N), and experience distortions on the sides, or cut the picture along the UTM zone borders, and make calculations within each UTM zone separately.

Comment: I was going to say that this projection is very strange. The central meridian crosses the +180 threshold and the spheroid parameters are unusual. It looks close to the GRS80 authalic sphere, but it's not quite there. Nice job.

Comment: This works great with good accuracy. For example, lower left corner which is `[-4228464.497,-835237.761]` in 'lcc' should result in `[-133.474506,12.162367]` based on photo from `gdalinfo` in my question. If I use what you suggested with `pyproj.Proj()`, I get `[-133.472937, 12.162813]` which is just `177` m apart using [Geod](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/pyproj/) function. I will  do my calculation within each UTM zone separately for sure. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this string in pyproj:

```
 Proj(proj='lcc', R=6371200, lat_1=25, lat_2=25,lon_0=-95, ellps='clrk66')
```

and my results were strange. when I changed the lat field names:

```
 Proj(proj='lcc', R=6371200, lat_0=25, lat_1=25,lon_0=-95, ellps='clrk66')
```

I got the results I was expecting.